# Pyspark can not delete file from HDFS containing backslash

Tags: python, hdfs, delete-file, backslash

Just noticed strange behaviour of either Python, Pyspark or maybe even Hadoop.
I have accidentally created a folder with a backslash in its name on HDFS:

```
>hdfs dfs -ls -h
drwxr-xr-x   -user hdfs          0 2020-08-04 08:59 Q2\solution2
```

I'm using Spark version 2.3.0.2.6.5.0-292 with Python 2.7.5.

So here is what I have tried. Start pyspark2, then execute following commands:

```
>import os
>os.system("hdfs dfs -rm -r -f 'Q2\solution2'")
0
```

file/folder is not deleted!

However, when I execute the same command directly from OS...

```
hdfs dfs -rm -r -f 'Q2\solution2'
```

The file/folder is deleted!

Can anyone explain why is this happening?

Comment: Given that you are using `os.system`, this isn't Pyspark or Python related. PySpark is able to import the FileSystem API for HDFS where you would be able to run the same Java function that `hdfs dfs rm` would

Comment: In any case, `"\s"` is likely your issue. Try `\\s`